# "Bus Error" in Cassandra and its python-driver

Tags: python, cassandra, odroid

I am working with cassandra on odroid-xu4 with its Ubuntu-14 image. (I also tried Ubuntu-15 image. (http://odroid.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=en:xu3_release_linux_ubuntu)
I installed the latest cassandra and its python driver.
However trying to connect to it from the cassandra python-driver gives a serios bus error and makes the python quit. Not even raises an exception.

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
k = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'])
k.connect() 
#crashes the python. Bus error appears on the command prompt/terminal
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction? Looks like some incompatibility between things. I confirm that I can successfully cqlsh to the cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
k.connect(keyspace)
```

?

Comment: I haven't created any keyspace so, I don't think I can do that. Anyway, why should it matter?

Comment: Try creating a keyspace first via cqlsh, then try again. Maybe it won't matter but it's a sound way to understand where the issue is.

Comment: Also, how did you install the driver?

Answer (score 0):

There was an alignment issue in earlier versions of the compiled deserialization extensions. This is resolved in [PYTHON-450](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-450) in driver version 3.1.0 and beyond.